# How to fix this error for Relay Basic tutorial "Unresolved reference: LocalTextStyle "?

Tags: android, kotlin, figma

> I've moved on each step provided in the basic tutorial for the hello world app, but When I've tried to run the app in Android studio after Importing the UI package, I've this error <sub>"app\build\generated\source\relay\debug\relay-runtime\com\google\relay\compose\RelayBaseComposables.kt: (26, 34): Unresolved reference: LocalTextStyle"</sub>
> In this file : RelayRelayBaseComposable.kt , This two lines are red alerted
> **`import androidx.compose.material.LocalTextStyle import androidx.compose.material.Text`**
> Any Idea to fix it?
> And may I ask if there is a limitation for using Relay as it some designs are not able to be imported giving errors as well.

I've tried to change the import lines from material to material3 and the red alert are being removed but when I start building the project, it back again to material not material3.

Edit**
I've found that my dependencies was not updated to it's last version, but after updating it, this error now appears : **`Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.`**

Answer (score 0):

You need this code.(Kotlin.version

build.gradle.kts (:app)

```
dependencies {     
  implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0") 
}
```

And please check this page
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#declaring_dependencies